# Trying to make slideshow "infinite" and back arrow is not functioning

Tags: html, css

I'm having two issues with a slideshow that I created. My first issue is that my back arrow doesn't work. So when I click it nothing happens. My second issue is that I am trying to make this slideshow infinite. By that I mean that when you get to the end of the slideshow (on slide 17) I want the next button to take you back to image number 1. I thought I had it with "next" and "previous" on each slide, bringing it back to it's original image (image 17's next image is image 1) but alas, it didn't work.

**By the way, I'm not actually making a puppy slideshow (but that would be a lot more fun wouldn't it??).

```css
.slides {
    padding: 0;
    width: 609px;
    height: 420px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}

.slides * {
    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.slides input { display: none; }

.slide-container { display: block; }

.slide {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 609px;
    height: 420px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;

    transform: scale(0);

    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.slide img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav label {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;

      opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    cursor: pointer;

    transition: opacity .2s;

    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 156pt;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 380px;
    font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.slide:hover + .nav label { opacity: 0.5; }

.nav label:hover { opacity: 1; }

.nav .next { right: 0; }

input:checked + .slide-container  .slide {
    opacity: 1;

    transform: scale(1);

    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { display: block; }

}
```

```html
<ul class="slides">
    <input type="radio" id="img-1" checked>
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="http://www.windowsmode.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Cute-Black-Dog.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-17" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" id="img-2">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://cdn-www.dailypuppy.com/dog-images/riley-the-golden-retriever_61755_2016-09-27_w450.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" id="img-3">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://www.adog.co.uk/dog-pictures/dogs-085.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" id="img-4">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="https://peopledotcom.files.wordpress.com/2017/05/downward-dog-3.jpg?w=2000&h=1334">
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" id="img-5">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://cdn.akc.org/content/hero/famous_dog_names_header_.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

        <input type="radio" id="img-6">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://www.dogster.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/laryngeal-paralysis-in-dogs.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-5" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-7" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

            <input type="radio" id="img-7">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://www.wallpaperstop.com/wallpapers/animal-wallpapers/dog-wallpapers/dog-picture-1280x1024-0010.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-8" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

            <input type="radio" id="img-8">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="https://karinalyudmilova.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/dogs.png">
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-7" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-9" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

            <input type="radio" id="img-9">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/cpsprodpb/E178/production/_91002775_dogspl.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-8" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-10" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

            <input type="radio" id="img-10">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://www.petinsurance.com/images/VSSimages/consumer/v5/banner_dog_insurance.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-9" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-11" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

                <input type="radio" id="img-11">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="https://www.petmd.com/sites/default/files/petmd-teacup-dogs.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-10" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-12" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

                <input type="radio" id="img-12">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.TRIchMXZiuFXfm-845GdYgEsDI&pid=15.1&P=0&w=247&h=165">
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-11" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-13" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

                <input type="radio" id="img-13">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://www.dw.com/image/36553143_303.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-12" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-14" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

                <input type="radio" id="img-14">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/articles/1362/large/the-five-main-reasons-behind-why-dogs-bite-52ff9d965af7b.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-13" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-15" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

                <input type="radio" id="img-15">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://www.greenfieldanimalhospital.com/clients/10589/images/dog.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-14" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-16" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

                <input type="radio" id="img-16">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="https://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.mLgGlpjW8HZi4RWHm5oGigEsCp&pid=15.1&P=0&w=299&h=170">
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-15" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-17" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

                <input type="radio" id="img-17">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://www.adog.co.uk/dog-pictures/dogs-068.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-16" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Did the answer provide work for you?

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give a name to your radio buttons.

Here is the JSFiddle working: https://jsfiddle.net/fpjm0ver/

Or if you prefer it, a code snippet.

```css
.slides {
  padding: 0;
  width: 609px;
  height: 420px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}

.slides * {
  user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.slides input {
  display: none;
}

.slide-container {
  display: block;
}

.slide {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 609px;
  height: 420px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav label {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 156pt;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 380px;
  font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.slide:hover + .nav label {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.nav label:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav .next {
  right: 0;
}

input:checked + .slide-container .slide {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked + .slide-container .nav label {
  display: block;
}


}
```

```html
<ul class="slides">
  <input name="carousel" type="radio" id="img-1" checked>
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://www.windowsmode.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Cute-Black-Dog.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-17" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input name="carousel" type="radio" id="img-2">
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://cdn-www.dailypuppy.com/dog-images/riley-the-golden-retriever_61755_2016-09-27_w450.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input name="carousel" type="radio" id="img-3">
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://www.adog.co.uk/dog-pictures/dogs-085.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input name="carousel" type="radio" id="img-4">
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://peopledotcom.files.wordpress.com/2017/05/downward-dog-3.jpg?w=2000&h=1334">
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input name="carousel" type="radio" id="img-5">
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://cdn.akc.org/content/hero/famous_dog_names_header_.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input name="carousel" type="radio" id="img-6">
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://www.dogster.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/laryngeal-paralysis-in-dogs.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-5" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-7" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input name="carousel" type="radio" id="img-7">
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://www.wallpaperstop.com/wallpapers/animal-wallpapers/dog-wallpapers/dog-picture-1280x1024-0010.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-8" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input name="carousel" type="radio" id="img-8">
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://karinalyudmilova.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/dogs.png">
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-7" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-9" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input name="carousel" type="radio" id="img-9">
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/cpsprodpb/E178/production/_91002775_dogspl.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-8" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-10" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input name="carousel" type="radio" id="img-10">
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://www.petinsurance.com/images/VSSimages/consumer/v5/banner_dog_insurance.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-9" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-11" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input name="carousel" type="radio" id="img-11">
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://www.petmd.com/sites/default/files/petmd-teacup-dogs.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-10" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-12" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input name="carousel" type="radio" id="img-12">
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.TRIchMXZiuFXfm-845GdYgEsDI&pid=15.1&P=0&w=247&h=165">
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-11" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-13" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input name="carousel" type="radio" id="img-13">
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://www.dw.com/image/36553143_303.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-12" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-14" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input name="carousel" type="radio" id="img-14">
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/articles/1362/large/the-five-main-reasons-behind-why-dogs-bite-52ff9d965af7b.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-13" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-15" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input name="carousel" type="radio" id="img-15">
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://www.greenfieldanimalhospital.com/clients/10589/images/dog.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-14" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-16" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input name="carousel" type="radio" id="img-16">
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.mLgGlpjW8HZi4RWHm5oGigEsCp&pid=15.1&P=0&w=299&h=170">
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-15" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-17" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input name="carousel" type="radio" id="img-17">
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://www.adog.co.uk/dog-pictures/dogs-068.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-16" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Without a name, every radio is a different one.